# How to set align to left or right in Python?

Tags: python, alignment, text-alignment, right-align

I'm a new here, and a new to Python.
In Python, how to move an align-self to left or right?
According to my codes below, how to move Atomic Number to upper on the left-hand side and Atomic Weight to lower on the left-hand side?
Here are the codes.

```
class Element(Button):
    def __init__(self, info, **kwargs):
        super(Element, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.info = info
        self.background_color = ELEMENT_COLOR_MAP[info["Element_Category"]]
        self.text = "[size=17]{}\n[/size][size=32][b]{}[/b][/size][size=17]\n{}[/size][size=17]\n{}[/size]".format(
            info['Atomic_Number'], info['Symbol'], info['Name'], info['Atomic_Weight'])
        self.text_size = self.size
        self.halign = 'center'
        self.valign = 'middle'
        self.markup = True
```

I've tried to change it many times, but it doesn't work anymore.
Please suggest me or fix it for me.
Thank you!

I tried to fix the code by changing `self.halign = 'left'`, but everything moved to the left side. I only want to move the Atomic Number (to the upper left-hand side) and Atomic Weight (to the lower left-hand side), while keeping the Symbol and Name in the middle positions.

Comment: This seems to be related to some GUI library. Add an appropriate tag and/or mention it in the question.

Comment: did you try `setStyleshett()` method??

Comment: I didn't try it. Thanks for your response.